# How to publish android Apk to Jfrog artifactory

Tags: android, artifactory

I want to upload my apk to Jfrog artifactory, i have seen artical to upload aar file on artifactory but doesn't find way to upload apk on artifactory.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily deploy any type of file or artifact to Artifactory via [REST api](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact) or using the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles).

for example, a simple REST deploy would look like:

```
curl -uMyUser:MyPassword -T <Path to your apk> "http://<Artifactory server>:port/artifactory/<Your Generic Repo>/<Your apk file path>"
```